# Cron job running while macbook lid is closed?

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, sleep-wake, launchd, cron

I have been using cron to run a script every morning at 5am daily (the script sends me an email with some data).

In the past, I have always had to keep my laptop lid **open** and awake for the cron job to execute (send me the email). I use the 'caffeinate' command to keep my laptop awake.

This past week my laptop lid has been closed at 5am, however, the cron job has executed twice.

**Does anyone know how the cron job is running even though my laptop lid is closed?**

I haven't terminated the 'caffeinate' process while my laptop has been closed. So perhaps this process is still doing something with the lid closed..? But if that's the case, why would the cron job execute only 2 days of the past week instead of every day?

Comment: How is the cronjob defined? Did you look at `/var/log/system.log` (and the older versions stored there) to check whether the Mac was or was not running at 5am?

Comment: The laptop was awake when the cron job should have kicked off, so it ran.  Do you perhaps use PowerNap?  If this script is important you might want to schedule a wake a minute or so before it's expected to run, rather than forcing the laptop to stay awake all the time.

Comment: Thanks @MarcWilson, I'll look into configuring a wake time. Right now my computer has PowerNap enabled only when connected to power, which it was not when the cron job ran. I looked into the system.log, and it appears my computer woke up at "Dec 28 04:53:36" for some reason. I can't really understand the log:
`Dec 28 04:53:36 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Dec 28 04:53:35 AM syslogd[60]: ASL Sender Statistics
Dec 28 04:53:36 AM remindd[67069]: objc[67069]: Class REMCDChangeTrackingState is implem...`

Comment: @nohillside, my cronjob runs a bash shell script that runs a node script "/usr/local/bin/node index.js"... Probably not the best way to do it. I'm in the learning process right now.

Comment: @nohillside, it appears my computer woke up at "Dec 28 04:53:36" for some reason. I can't really understand the log: `Dec 28 04:53:36 --- last message repeated 1 time --- Dec 28 04:53:35 AM syslogd[60]: ASL Sender Statistics Dec 28 04:53:36 AM remindd[67069]: objc[67069]: Class REMCDChangeTrackingState is implem...`

Comment: The interesting part is the time definition, so basically the result of `crontab -l`. And please edit your question with the log output, it‘s hard to read in comments.

Comment: I suggest you use `launchd` on mac instead of crontab. You can find a tutorial here. https://www.launchd.info/